# Number of bounded Dyck paths with "negative length"

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, generating-functions

Let $c(n,k)$ denote the number of Dyck paths of semilength $n$ which are contained in the strip $0 \leq y \leq 2k + 1.$

They satisfy the recursion $\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}(-1)^j \binom{2k+2-j}{j}c(n-j,k)=0$ for $n>k.$

We can extend the sequence to negative $n$ such that this recursion holds for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}.$
I am interested in the generating function of the  sequence ${\left( {c( - n,k)} \right)_{n \geq 0}}.$

It is well known that $\sum\limits_{n \geq 0} {c(n,k){x^n}}  = \frac{{{F_{2k + 1}}( - x)}}{{{F_{2k + 2}}( - x)}}$ if  by ${F_n}(x) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{\left\lfloor {\frac{n}{2}} \right\rfloor } \binom{n-j}{j}
x^j $  we  denote the Fibonacci polynomials which satisfy ${F_n}(x) = {F_{n - 1}}(x) + x{F_{n - 2}}(x)$ with initial values  $F_0(x)=F_1(x)=1.$

Computations for small $k$ suggest that $\sum\limits_{n \geq 0} {c( - n,k){x^n}}  =  - \frac{1}{x}\frac{{{F_{2k}}( - \frac{1}{x})}}{{{F_{2k + 2}}( - \frac{1}{x})}}.$
As mentioned in OEIS A080937 and A038213 for $n=2$   this result is due to Michael Somos.

These generating functions imply that $c(n,k)$ satisfies the recursion for $\left| n \right| > k.$

But to show that $c(-n,k)$ is the looked for extension we need the recursion for all $n$.  Any idea how to do this?

Comment: These $F_n(x)$ are different from the conventional [Fibonacci polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_polynomials).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $f(n)$ satisfies a linear recurrence with constant coefficients for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and we set $F(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} f(n)x^n$, then $\sum_{n\geq 1}f(-n)x^n = -F(1/x)$ (as rational functions). See *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 1, second ed., Prop. 4.2.3.

**Addendum.** Using Exercise 3.66(d) in *Enumerative Combinatorics*,
vol. 1, second ed., it is not hard to show that $c(-n,k)$ is equal
to the number of sequences $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{2n-1})$ of positive
integers satisfying $1\leq a_i\leq k+1$ and $a_1\leq a_2 \geq a_3 \leq
  a_4 \geq \cdots\geq a_{2n-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Is there a combinatorial interpretation of the numbers $c(-n,k)$ related to Dyck paths?

Comment: there seems to be an interpretation in the OEIS, which links to http://home.wxs.nl/~lamoen/wiskunde/wave.htm

Comment: For example, the sequence for k=4 is apparently the dissection of https://oeis.org/A006358

Comment: @Martin Rubey:This can be formulated in the following way: 
Let $M_k$ be the matrix with entries $m(i,j,k)$ for $0\leq{i,j}\leq{k-1}$ such that $m(i,j,k)=0$ for $i+j<k-1$ and $m(i,j,k)=1$ else and let $v_k$ be the vector with all entries $1.$ 

The claim is that $c(-n,k)$ is the first entry of $M_k^{2n}v_k$.This can be verified for small $k$.  The recursions are the same, but I cannot see how the initial values coincide in the general case.